# Magento 2: Move text "This is a required field" below swatch options

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, design

When a user don't select a size option and clicks the "Add to cart" button, the warning "This is a required field" appears under the button.

I'd like that warning appear just **below the swatches**, not below the "Add to cart" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

Copy above file into your custom theme, `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

```
if ($widget.productForm) {
    $widget.productForm.append(input);
    input = '';
}
```

Inside new file replace above code with below code

```
 if ($widget.productForm) {
    $widget.productForm.find('.product-options-bottom').before(input);
    input = '';
}
```

run command,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Remove **var** folder and check again.

Comment: I had to manually delete /pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js before running setup:static-content:deploy. Only after deleting the target file it updated the correct file.