# Magento 2 Want to move the "This Is A Required Field" attribute message below the Color Swatch

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, color-swatches

[image: Currently the message shows up twice below the Add The Cart button.]

I have tried [this fix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135972/magento-2-move-text-this-is-a-required-field-below-swatch-options) but it did not work. I wondered if anyone else had any suggestions. I am in M2.1.2 using a custom theme based on the parent blank theme.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this on [git hub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5428?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)

That worked for me although I also had to clear my static files and redeploy theme to get it to work. Not quite sure why.